# playing music with relative paths with phonegap build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm developing a jquery mobbile app which is compiled with phonegap build in the cloud. I downloaded a sample script for playing media and my problem is i can't seem to pick up the music source from my folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
                  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Media Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            playAudio("/music/insider.mp3");
        }

        // Audio player
        //
        var my_media = null;
        var mediaTimer = null;

        // Play audio
        //
        function playAudio(src) {
            // Create Media object from src
            my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

            // Play audio
            my_media.play();

            // Update my_media position every second
            if (mediaTimer == null) {
                mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                    // get my_media position
                    my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                        // success callback
                        function(position) {
                            if (position > -1) {
                                setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                            }
                        },
                        // error callback
                        function(e) {
                            console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                            setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                        }
                    );
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

        // Pause audio
        // 
        function pauseAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.pause();
            }
        }

        // Stop audio
        // 
        function stopAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.stop();
            }
            clearInterval(mediaTimer);
            mediaTimer = null;
        }

        // onSuccess Callback
        //
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }

        // onError Callback 
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        // Set audio position
        // 
        function setAudioPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
        }

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio('/music/insider.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="pauseAudio();">Pause Playing Audio</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="stopAudio();">Stop Playing Audio</a>
        <p id="audio_position"></p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Which platform(s) are you targeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need to access a file from the app bundle:
Try to use `playAudio(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/music/insider.mp3");` in this case.

Note that on Windows platform `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` incorrectly points to `ms-appdata:///` instead of `ms-appx:///` so as a workaround you can use something like this for now:

```
if (cordova.platformId === 'windows') {
    playAudio('ms-appx:///www/music/insider.mp3');
} else {
    playAudio(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/music/insider.mp3");
}
```

See [the file plugin docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files) for other options.

Comment: i don't have a www folder within my app. My folder on the the drive c: for example c:myapp/music/insider.mp3

Comment: FWIW:since you NEVER mention your desktop computer was the issue, it was presumed you meant the mobile device. Correct your original post is that is what you want. Otherwise, i would suggest you [read the docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files)